# Como trabalhar com Labels em CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Quando utilizamos de atributos como `Label` o texto é escrito da esquerda para direita. Podemos mudar isso? Fazer com que o texto comece  por exemplo do meio para os lados ou da direita para esquerda ?

Exemplo:

----> Esquerda para direita

|MEU TEXTO ----|

Como preciso (+ é o centro)

<---- ---->

|  Ipan + ema    |

ou

<<<<<<  Direita para Esquerda

| ---- MEU TEXTO|

Será isso possível?
Obrigado !

Comment: Gostaria de fazer isso sem englobar em uma `div` e utilizar text `align certer` ou `Right`...

Comment: Não ficou muito claro a finalidade. Poste o código que você já tem até agora.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi se sua pergunta é sobre alinhamento ou orientação na escrita. Vou responder os dois então.

**ALINHAMENTO**

Alinhar um `<label>` à esquerda:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:left">
    <label>MEU TEXTO</label>
</div>
```

Alinhar um `<label>` centralizado:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
    <label>MEU TEXTO</label>
</div>
```

Alinhar um `<label>` à direita:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right">
    <label>MEU TEXTO</label>
</div>
```

[Veja demonstração aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/gmp7ykf1/).

**ORIENTAÇÃO**

Da direita para esquerda:

```
<div style="direction:ltr;">
    <label>MEU TEXTO</label>
</div>
```

Da esquerda para direita:

```
<div style="direction:rtl;">
    <label>MEU TEXTO</label>
</div>
```

[Veja demonstração aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/bj4sfbrz/).

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem mas pelo que entendi você quer isso:

```css
            label{display:block;}
            form{width: 200px;border: 3px solid #4e4e4e;padding: 15px 15px;border-radius: 3px;}
            label#label-01{text-align: left;}
            label#label-02{text-align: right;}
            label#label-03{text-align: center;}
            input{width: 100%;}
```

```html
        <form action="">
            <label for="" id="label-01">Label 01</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br><br>
            <label for="" id="label-02">Label 02</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br><br>
            <label for="" id="label-03">Label 03</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br><br>
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
```